# TypeScript: list files in web folder

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript web application with the following folder structure.

```
- assets
 |- a.png
 |- b.png
 |- c.png
 |- d.png
 |- ...
- app.ts
```

In `app.ts`, how do I programatically list all the files in `assets` folder?

I tried the below but it didn't work. And I also thought I may be going down the wrong path because `fs` is used to access the user's file system, which is not my intent.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const assets_folder = './assets/';
fs.readdirSync(assets_folder).forEach((file) => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to file location because when you use the typescript after compiling., it'll move to dist/build and it'll look in that directory.

Solution: Copy files/directory from src to dist/build programatically, it'll solve your issue.

Project src

```
src
  assets
    images
  app.ts
```

After complie

```
dist
  //<Missing assets>
  app.js
```

Comment: wow thanks. so the same code that i provided above using `fs` will work once i move the files?

Comment: @chongzixin it should work.

Comment: having a separate issue `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` now. Will resolve that then validate this. thanks!